# How to set width of MDL TextArea

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-design-lite

What is the best way to set the width of a Material Design Lite multi-line TextField?  I set the CSS width to a pixel value, and it works, but when you click on it to enter some text, the underline highlighting does not extent out to the full width of the component.  I tried cols="80" and that did not work.  I also tried width="100%" and that did not work.  I'm working in ReactJS and TypeScript if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The width needs to be set on the `mdl-textfield` container div for the text field. For example, this works:

```
.mdl-textfield{
    width:500px;
}
```

Though that will style all of your textfields. If you only want one of them to be that wide, then define an id or class on the same div as has the `mdl-textfield` class and apply the style to that. For example:

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield extrawide">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1">Text...</label>
</div>
```

with the css

```
.extrawide{
    width:500px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the info.